# Git bash on Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu

How to add branch name into console line like it made in Windows Bash

```
foo@bar MINGW64 /d/_GitRepo/game (master)
$
```

and change color theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to show the current branch in the terminal command line, this site could help you https://techcommons.stanford.edu/topics/git/show-git-branch-bash-prompt

To summarize:

Put this function in your `.bashrc`

```
function parse_git_branch {
  git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
```

It extracts the current branch.
Then edit value of the PS1 variable and call the function you created with `$(parse_git_branch)`. It should look similar to this:

```
PS1="\h:\W \u$BLUE\$(parse_git_branch) $DEFAULT\$"
```

Comment: I haven't .bashrc, so i just create it - which resulted to the fact that all of the text console is now gray but with a branch name)

Comment: @ikimaru2013: Search for a default `.bashrc` for you distribution and just add the function call to the existing `PS1`. In some distributions you can find a default one under `\etc\skel`.