# Change Ubuntu terminal to look like Git-bash of Window

Tags: git, terminal, git-bash, ubuntu-18.04

Is there a way to change/replace the default Ubuntu terminal with Git-bash(look and behavior) of Window? Basically, the terminal should display all the necessary information related with current branch/repo, just like it does in Window.

I am using VS Code and had configured Git-Bash with it for [Window platform](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_windows). But couldn't find anything which would let me achieve the same on Ubuntu platform.

I have checked following links for answers -

1. [Git bash on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34769621/git-bash-on-ubuntu#answer-34769934). -> After changes, it shows current branch but all entire text/string becomes monotonous white.
2. [How can I have a shell for git like in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168115/how-can-i-have-a-shell-for-git-like-in-windows/#answer-175106). -> Only branch name's text-color remains as green and everything else becomes white.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After **@kostix** suggestion, I searched the internet with proper key-words and found [this question thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730754/how-do-i-show-the-git-branch-with-colours-in-bash-prompt) and then finally to [this page](https://coderwall.com/p/fasnya/add-git-branch-name-to-bash-prompt). After trying approaches mentioned there, I ended up with the following code which works much better. Add these code in the `.bashrc` file present in `Home` folder. Find it using `~/.bashrc/` command.

```
# git branch info if present
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] \n\[\033[1;31m\]>>\[\033[00m\] "
```

**Ubuntu's terminal screenshot -**

[image]

**VS code's terminal screenshot -**

[image]

You can update the code to alter color code(s) depending on your choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback on your research!

Comment: Thanks! It works great on windows as well as on amazon linux.
I switched back to single dollar sing, though:
`export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] \n\[\033[1;31m\]$ \[\033[00m\]"`

Comment: Still, there is one pending info, that is related to the merge conflicts. Git bash shows "MERGING" when merge conflicts occur locally. Right now, my answer doesn't include that option. I will update it once I find that solution.

Comment: Another variation I like [HERE](https://gist.github.com/justintv/168835#gistcomment-1717504) `export PS1='\[\033[0;32m\]\[\033[0m\033[0;32m\]\u\[\033[0;36m\] @ \[\033[0;36m\]\h \w\[\033[0;32m\]$(__git_ps1)\n\[\033[0;32m\]└─\[\033[0m\033[0;32m\] \$\[\033[0m\033[0;32m\] ▶\[\033[0m\] '`

Answer (score -3):

Git bash does nothing special there: it's just a port to Windows of a stock `bash` shell.

"The trick" (not) here is the tweaks applied to the *startup script* of `bash` to make it have that fancy dynamically generated *prompt.*
These tweaks, again, call nothing special but plain Git commands.

Now just please do your further research and apply the tweaks GfW does to your local `bash` setup.

Comment: After your answer, I corrected my approach to finding the answer of my question. Thank you.